# Issue with STI and Factory Girl Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rspec3

I am having an issue with my classes not being set appropriately when dealing with a Single Table Inheritance class and factory girl.

My Factory is:

```
  factory :team do
        name "Test name"
        store_password 'password'
  end

  factory :sales_team, class: Team, parent: :team do
        type 'SalesTeam'
  end

  factory :retail_sales_team, class: Team, parent: :team do
        type 'RetailSalesTeam'
  end
```

(I have also tried it with the :sales_team and :retail_sales_team nested inside the factory :team do)

And in my spec I do

```
@team = FactoryGirl.create(:retail_sales_team, name: "Test Team")
```

If I then call

```
@team.class.name #=> "Team"
```

And when I try to pass @team to an object that

```
belongs_to :team , class_name: 'RetailSalesTeam'
```

I get the error

```
 Failure/Error: @sale = FactoryGirl.create(:sale, kpi: @kpi, user: @user, team: @team)
 ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:
   RetailSalesTeam(#70151785667180) expected, got Team(#70151730184960)
```

Let me know if there is any other information I can provide and thanks in advance!

Comment: Why say `class: Team` if you don't want them to be instances of Team?

Comment: Oh man I can't believe that the answer was so simple... Thank you so much for your help! Write it as an answer and I will accept it.